# CKEditor with uploadImage plugin returns the entire VF page in salesforce

Tags: ckeditor, salesforce, visualforce

I have a ckEditor with uploadimage on my VF page. I have configured it as

```
config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
config.imageUploadUrl = 'apex/SiteFileUploaderBackup';
```

I am yet to fully develop the SiteFileUploaderBackup page and the controller. Just tried with a dummy code.

This is my VF page :

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="SiteFileUploadControllerbackup">

    <script>
        function getUrlParam(paramName){
          var reParam = new RegExp('(?:[\?&]|&amp;)' + paramName + '=([^&]+)', 'i') ;
          var match = window.location.search.match(reParam) ;
          return (match && match.length > 1) ? match[1] : '' ;
        }

        var funcNum = getUrlParam('CKEditorFuncNum');
        console.log('***  funcNum=' + funcNum);

        var str = '{"fileName":"kingston-visitor-chair-black-med.jpg","uploaded":1,"error":{"number":201,"message":"A file with the same name already exists. The uploaded file was renamed to \u0022kingston-visitor-chair-black-med(3).jpg\u0022."},"url":"https:\/\/cadence--cos2--c.cs14.content.force.com\/servlet\/servlet.ImageServer?id=015c00000003hQm&oid=00Dc0000003w9jE&lastMod=1511435219000"}';
        if(funcNum == null)
                window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum,str);                     
        else                    
            window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('{!funcNumber}', str );               
        window.close() ;
    </script>
```

And the controller just has the constructor

```
public class SiteFileUploadControllerbackup {
public String funcNumber {get; set;} 
public SiteFileUploadControllerBackup()
{
    string ckEditorFunc = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CKEditorFuncNum'); 
    if(funcNumber == null)
        funcNumber = ckEditorFunc; 
   }
```

}

Since this is a stub code I am just looking for correct ResponseText which should be the json I used in VF page. However I am always getting 
    Error code: filetools-response-error. and the responseText contains the entire HTML of the VF page.

I searched a lot but could not find any sample VF -apex code which can help. Any help on how to get the json in responseText would be appreciated.